CORS Error in React when try to access Anthropic API
I am trying to access Anthropic Claude API in React.
I tried two methods:

One is API Call with the Axios
And Second is using Anthropic AI SDK for Typescript

In both methods, i am getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error in console.
I also tried CORS Anywhere browser extension and React Proxy but getting same error.
SDK Code from my React component below:
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const anthropic = new Anthropic({
      apiKey: "API KEY",
    });
    const msg = await anthropic.messages.create({
      model: "claude-3-opus-20240229",
      max_tokens: 1024,
      messages: [{ role: "user", content: "Hello, Claude" }],
    });
    console.log(msg);

Calling Claude API, Expecting the Results in response, but I get CORS error.

I've never utilized Anthropic AI before, but typically, you can configure the allowed hosts in your API settings. This enables your local development environment to access the API.

Thank you for your comment. You are right but i can't see any option to edit the API response in Claude/Anthropic website.

Only other alternative I can think of is using a proxy

Thank you! I already tried proxy but had same issue.  I’ll give it one more shot
